# Como introducir un boton desplegable que tenga el aspecto de 3 puntos en Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, django

Quiero que en mi `post_card` aparezca un botón desplegable que tenga esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que al apretar me salga la opción de eliminar o editar ese post.

Dejo el código del HTML `post_card.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 mt-5 p-0 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded post-container">

    <a href="{% url 'posts:detail' post.pk %}">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="{{ post.photo.url }}" >
    </a>

    <p class="ml-2 mt-0 mb-2">
        <b>{{ post.title }}</b> - <small>{{ post.created }}</small>
    </p>

    <p>
        <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />







<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

En bootstrap eso lo consigues con un dropdown. Ten en cuenta que los 3 puntos verticales usados en este ejemplo son de fontawesome, tendrás que añadir ese css. O cambiar '' por otra cosa.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo de cómo crear un botón de 3 puntos con CSS (sin funcionalidad):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Boton 3 puntos</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            box-sizing : border-box;
            margin     : 0;
            padding    : 0;
            text-align : center;
        }

        .btn {
            background    : lightgrey;
            border-radius : 3px;
            border        : 1px solid darkgrey;
            color         : grey;
            display       : inline-block;
            font-size     : 1.5rem;
            padding       : .8rem;
        }
        .btn:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .custom-btn {
            font-family : monospace;
            margin      : 1rem;
            padding-top : .3rem;
        }
        .vertical {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="btn custom-btn">
        ...
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="btn custom-btn vertical">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Si estas usando *Bootstrap* solo necesitas las clases CSS: `custom-btn` y `vertical`, la clave para disponer los puntos en vertical esta la última, la primera es para otros ajustes de la apariencia del botón.